# Embedding private Google Drive Images on Website

Tags: javascript, html, google-drive-api

I have a Google Drive folder with images in it, which needs to be kept "*Restricted: Only people added can open with this link*" because our Drive needs to stay HIPAA Compliant. I created a web app where users log in using their Google accounts and should be able to view those images directly from the web app (because they also have access to the Google Drive folder). I was able to embed the images using the following link structure: `https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=` + [fileID] .

It works great on Chrome but does not work on Safari and on mobile devices - it simply shows a blank image, although it appears when I go to the image's link. When I make the folder public it works on all browsers/devices, so I assume the issue is with the restricted access. Is there a way to circumvent this?

Idea: Since I have the users authentication tokens, I was thinking I could make an iFrame where I load the image URL and I set the cookies using their tokens, so Drive would know that they have access to the images. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Just a thought, but how about using [blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) by sending a request via Javascript with proper Authorization header and embedding images via one?

Comment: That's a good idea! I just coded it up and it seems to work!! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @Stefan Glad it helped!